# Does the matrix equation $\text{A}^k=\epsilon \text{A}$ have any $\text{A}\neq I_n$ solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

The question was recently posed to myself and some peers of whether or not the equation $$\text{A}^k=\epsilon\text{A}\ \Big|\ k, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}, $$ where A is $n\times n\ \big|\ n>1,$ has any matrix solutions A $\neq I_n.$ My curiosity is killing, and I cannot find any sufficient resources online.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you really intend for $k$ to be a real number instead of a non-negative integer? Also, you might want to look at projection matrices. Any projection matrix $P$ will satisfy $P^2 = P$, and thus, $P^k = P$ for all integers $k \ge 1$.

Comment: Can you clarify how $A^k$ is defined?

Comment: There are a ton of such matrices -- in addition to idempotent matrices, consider rotations about any axis by $2\pi/(k-1)$ degrees, etc etc

Comment: Specifically I'm consider all values of $k$ that are odd positive integers. As stated, A is $n\times n$.

Comment: There are numerous matrices that satisfy $A^k=A$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$. For example, $\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)^4=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$.

Comment: Those matrices I will consider trivial; allow the question to be restated for all values of $\epsilon\neq 1$.

Comment: Does your equation need to hold for *one* $\epsilon$ and *all* $k$? Or one $\epsilon$ and one $k$?

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable then $A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$. So, for integer $k$ the equation reduces to $\Lambda^k-\epsilon\Lambda=0$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal...

Comment: Let $\epsilon$ be arbitrary. Then for any $A$ satisfying $A^k=A$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $B=\epsilon^{\frac{1}{k-1}}A$ satisfies $B^k=\epsilon B$.

Answer (score 6):

For any positive integer $k$ and any $\epsilon$, the solutions of $A^k = \epsilon A$ include all diagonalizable matrices whose eigenvalues are roots
of the polynomial $z^k - \epsilon z$ (thus $0$ and $k-1$'th roots of $\epsilon$).  For non-integer $k$, if you specify a branch of $z^k$, you can define $A^k$ by the holomorphic functional calculus using that  branch if the branch is analytic in a neighbourhood of the eigenvalues of $A$; $A$ will then satisfy $A^k = \epsilon A$ if $A$ is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are zeros of $z^k - \epsilon z$ (using that branch of $z^k$).

EDIT: For $\epsilon \ne 0$ and positive integer $k$, the roots of $z^k - \epsilon z$ are all simple, so all solutions $A$  are diagonalizable (any matrix whose minimal polynomial has simple roots is diagonalizable).